# Count number of rows of specific mysql columns that are not empty

Tags: php, mysql, count, rows

I have a mysql table with an x amount of columns. I would like to check if the rows of a specific columns are empty or not ..

Currently I have:

```
$query10 ("SELECT count(*) FROM content WHERE linkname IS NOT NULL")     or die(mysql_error());
$result10 = mysql_query($query10);
$row10 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query10);
echo $row10['0'];
```

But I get an error:

Fatal error: Function name must be a string in ... on line 227

I never used count, before I used num_rows .. but can't seem to get it to work with that either ..

So just to make clear, my table looks like

```
|  column1  |   column2   |   column3  |
--------------------------------------------
|     a     |      b       |              |
---------------------------------------------
|     a2    |      b2      |      c2      |
----------------------------------------------
|     a3    |      b3      |              |
```

I want to count al rows of column3 that are  not empty, so in this case the result of count should be 1.

counting gives following error:

mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Thanks so much

Comment: There is an error `$query10 ("SELECT count(*) FROM content WHERE linkname IS NOT NULL")`  you are storing query in variable i guess, so do like this `$query10 = "SELECT count(*) FROM content WHERE linkname IS NOT NULL";` removed parenthesis

Comment: Thanks Murtaza, dumb me .. that solved the error

Comment: Please use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of MySQL. MySQL is deprecated and removed in PHP 7.0.

Comment: just replace mysql with mysqli?

Comment: No, that is not how it is working :)

First you have to connect with [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php). After that you can setup your [query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) and the `fetch_assoc` function is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Comment: I will try and rewrite the code to actual php syntax with mysqli, I promiss, but for now


    $query10 = "SELECT count(linkname) FROM content as total";
    $result10 = mysql_query($query10);
    while($rows10 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result10)){echo $rows10['total'];
    }


should work, but it isn't ..

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `<> ''` instate of `IS NOT NULL`

`SELECT count(*) FROM content WHERE linkname <> ''`

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60622/9)

And as *Murtaza Bhurgri* says `$query10 ("SELECT count(*) FROM content WHERE linkname IS NOT NULL")     or die(mysql_error());` this will definitely give error. it should be something like

```
$query10 = "SELECT count(*) FROM content WHERE linkname <> ''";
$result10 = mysql_query( $query10 );
if ( !$result10 ) {
    die( 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() );
}
$row10 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result10);
echo $row10[0];
```

Comment: I added the 'as total' otherwise mysql_fetch_assoc doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, which works:

```
$query10 = "SELECT count(*) as total FROM content WHERE linkname <> '' AND content.album_id = $album_id  ";
$result10 = mysql_query( $query10 );
if ( !$result10 ) {
    die( 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() );
}
$row10 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result10);
echo "zo veel:".$row10[total];
```

I added the 'content.album_id = $album_id', since I want this only for more specific columns

and sorry for being in deprecated mode ..

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database');

$query10 = "SELECT COUNT(linkname) AS linkname_rows_count FROM tbl WHERE linkname != '' AND linkname IS NOT NULL";
$result10 = mysql_query($query10);

if(isset($result10)) {
    $row10 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result10);
    echo $row10['linkname_rows_count'];
}
```

The rows in the specific column you mentioned may contain an empty string or a `null` value. The query you used only checks against the `null` value. Moreover, whenever you use `COUNT` function with the column passed in its parameter, assign an alias to that to make the `result set` easy to be handled.

Also, your code uses deprecated `mysql` extension. You need to migrate to `mysqli` or `PDO` to secure your code against attacks like `SQL Injection`. So, I've also given you alternative code written using `mysqli` functions.

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'database');
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(linkname) AS linkname_rows_count FROM tbl WHERE linkname != '' AND linkname IS NOT NULL";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if(isset($query)) {
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo $result['linkname_rows_count'];
}
```

Hope it helps!